# Flask WTF Forms

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have the following function which just selects data from the database and assigns it to variables.

```
@app.route("/tasks")
@login_required
def tasks():
    g.db = connect_db()
    data = g.db.execute("""
            SELECT name, due_date, priority, task_id
            FROM tasks where status = 1
        """)
    open_tasks = [dict(name=row[0], due_date=row[1], priority=row[2], task_id=row[3])
                  for row in data.fetchall()]

    data = g.db.execute("""
            SELECT name, due_date, priority, task_id
            FROM tasks where status = 0
        """)
    closed_tasks = [dict(name=row[0], due_date=row[1], priority=row[2], task_id=row[3])
                  for row in data.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template(
        'tasks.html',
        form=AddTaskForm(request.form),
        open_tasks=open_tasks,
        closed_tasks=closed_tasks
    )
```

But what I can't understand is `form=AddTaskForm(request.form)`. The `task.html` is already a form as you can see here:

```
<div class="add_task">
    <h3>Add a new task</h3>
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_task') }}" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Task Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Due Date: </label>
            <input type="text" name="due_date">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Priority</label>
            <select name="priority">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

So why did (the author of this tutorial) assign it to `AddTaskForm(request.form)` ?

The code for `forms.py` where `AddTaskForm` comes from is below:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, DateField, IntegerField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class AddTaskForm(Form):
    task_id = IntegerField()
    name = StringField("Task Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    due_date = DateField(
        "Due Date",
        validators = [DataRequired()],
        format = '%m/%d/%y'
    )
    priority = SelectField(
        'Priority',
        validators = [DataRequired()],
        choices = [
            ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'),
            ('6', '6'), ('7', '7'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '9'), ('10', '10')
        ]
    )
    status = IntegerField('Status')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, since the form and it's action are never used in your function/route/method. So if your where to use the form to create a Task:
you would:

```
# Initialization etc.
form = AddTaskForm(request.form)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    # Do whatever with the submited data
return render_template("task.html", form=form, ...)
```

So basically you could render results and accept Form-Data in the same method

Comment: What do you mean by `# Initialization etc.` and `# Do whatever with the submited data`. What should I replace them with ?

Comment: Initialization: set the variables for the template in your example `open_tasks` and `closed_tasks` and the `form` then you check if the form is submitted and valid `form.validate_on_submit()` if the form is submitted and valid -> you can access the posted `form.name.data` etc. check the [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation.